# Zoom in and zoom out by double tap works only first time..how to fix this? [ANDROID]

Tags: android, zooming

i am creating an app where i have to zoom in and zoo out images on double tap just like zooming images in normal android devices. In my case my code works fine but for one time only. On first time double tap images zooms in perfectely and on 2nd double tap it zooms out perfectly but on thrid time double tap nothing happes.How to fix this? any help will be appreciated
Here is my code

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView iv;
ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
private Matrix original_matrix = new Matrix();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_demo_gestures);
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.demoimg), size.x, size.y, true);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    original_matrix = iv.getImageMatrix();
    iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(SecondActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            boolean check_zoom_state = false;
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                if(check_zoom_state==false) {
                    float scalefactor = Math.max(1.1f, Math.min(3.0f, 4.0f));
                    float x = e.getX();
                    float y = e.getY();
                    matrix.setScale(scalefactor, scalefactor, x, y);
                    iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    check_zoom_state=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //iv.setImageMatrix(original_matrix);
                     iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

                }
                   return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
               //iv.setImageMatrix(original_matrix);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Pressed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            }

        });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = x2 - x1;

                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        // Left to Right swipe action
                        if (x2 > x1)
                        {
                           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left to Right swipe [Next]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }

                        // Right to left swipe action
                        /*else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right to Left swipe [Previous]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }*/

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
                    }
                    break;
            }
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: use [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/tree/master/src/com/ortiz/touch)

Comment: Please try adding this, "check_zoom_state = false;" inside the "else" of onDoubleTap().

Comment: @I_A_Mok ypp i have added it. i forgot to mention here. but still the problem is same

Comment: @vrundpurohit i have downloaded it...how i can add it in my android studio project?

Comment: just copy `TouchImageView` in your project and replace your `ImageView` with `TouchImageView` and You are done